# Unable to execute the queries in .sql file in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server-2017

On saving a SQL query file in SQL Server 2017 and loading the Microsoft SQL Server query file (`.sql`) with SSMS, I cannot execute the queries I have written in the `.sql` file but when I copy and paste the queries onto a new query created on the database, the same query is able to execute. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

STR:

1. Open the exiting saved `.sql` file with SSMS
2. Execute the query in the `.sql` file
3. Unable to run the query
4. Copy the query and paste into a new query file created on the database
5. The query is able to execute.

Note: the `.sql` file was created in SQL Server 2017

This issue keeps occurring when I open previous `.sql` file and it has become an hassle to copy and paste it into a new query file by right clicking on the database and selecting new query.

[On loading the .sql file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siTCK.png)

[I can only connect to the master database  but not the database that I'm targeting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9CPV.png)

[After connecting to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7eJx.png)

Comment: if you open a sql-file it’s not connected.

Comment: you have to connect the query.

Comment: i am connecting to the database on loading the .sql file. 
Also Disconnect after the query executes: option is already unchecked.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23077/how-to-connect-once-for-all-queries-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: You are connecting to the database-server, not the database. If you’re connecting you are connected to the master database by default. you have to change it to the database you‘re targeting.

Comment: Yes Nikolaus, can you please tell me how do i change it to the database that im targeting ?

Comment: There should be a drop-down above the Server-tree with master as value- change it to the desired database.

Comment: is it the same drop down ur referring to in the pic attached "I can only connect to the master database but not the database that I'm targeting"

I can only connect to the master database but not the child database that i am targetting

Comment: No, after you connected to the server( your picture), above the object-explorer, there should be the drop-down

Comment: It’s above the Server-Explorer-Window and contains the word master by default.

Comment: If the database-name is always the same, you can also add a using statement in your.sql file

Comment: could you resolve your issue?